# How to get/update 'Contacts' within Active Directory?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

is there a way to find and update the contacts in Active Directory? I'm building a sample C# .NET application to achieve this task. I would appreciate any code.

Comment: What do you mean by "contacts"?? What "contacts"?? AD stores user and computer accounts, security and distribution groups and more - but "contacts" is a new term for AD - never heard it....

Comment: Contacts are just like an ordinary AD objects like users, computer and they appear in Exchange Server as a Mail Contact. In most cases, they have an external email address aka smtp address.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course, you can do it in System.DirectoryServices.

I think what you really need is to learn how to use [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx).  If you don't have a good book yet, I recommend [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321350170).

It's not that hard, really.  You just need to master two classes, [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) and [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx).  [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) is representing a LDAP object on the LDAP server.  Assuming you have sufficient permissions, you can make changes on any LDAP object, including the contact object using [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx).  Each LDAP object has a number of attributes.  TWo important attributes you need to know are `objectCategory` and `objectClass`.  For the contact object, the `objectCategory` should be `person` and `objectClass` should be `contact`.  You may also like to check the "targetAddress" attribute on the contact object, which stores the email address.  There are a bunch of Exchange extended attributes on contact object.  You probably like to check each of them one by one.  To browse the objects on LDAP server, you can use a tool like [AD Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907) or [ADSI Edit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354(WS.10).aspx)

To do a search, you need to provider four things to [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx).

1. Search root
2. LDAP search filter
3. Search Scope
4. Returned attributes

If your machine is already joined to a domain and you are logging in as a domain user, here is a sample on how to list out all contacts in your domain.

```
DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
string domainContext = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value as string;
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domainContext);
using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(
    searchRoot, 
    "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=contact))", 
    new string[] {"targetAddress"}, 
    SearchScope.Subtree))
{
    foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
    {
        foreach (string addr in result.Properties["targetAddress"])
        {        
           Console.WriteLine(addr);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result.Path);
    }
}
```

The first three lines are to help you to find the correct LDAP path to the root of your domain.  It works only if you are logging in as a domain user.  If you know the correct LDAP path of your domain, you can just feed it into DirectoryEntry directly.

I put all four parameters into [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx).  When you are getting familiar with Directory Services programming, you can skip some of them and .NET will provide a default value for you.

The result returned from [DiectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) is [SearchResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.aspx).  Note that [SearchResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.aspx) always return a collection of objects to you even though `targetAddress` is not a multivalue attribute.  It's because some of the attributes on the LDAP object may be multi-value.

Another important information you can get from [SearchResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.aspx) is the `Path`.  You can create a [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) object using this Path later.  To update your contact object, you need to use its `Properties` method and `CommitChanges` method.

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(result.Path);
de.Properties["targetAddress"].Value = "SMTP:jane.doe@foo.bar";
de.CommitChanges();
```

Finally, you can actually easily find a lot of online tutorial on both [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) and [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx).  Try google it.

Comment: Many thanks for detailed reply. The question remains on how can I add multiple email addresses to the Contact's object.

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean updating properties on a user object in Active Directory. And yes this is possible.

With .Net 3.5 we got the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace which makes dealing with AD a lot simpler compared to what was in the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace before.

Typically to modify properties of a user (if you have access to save) you would do something like:

```
string sUserName = "someusertoload";
string sDomain = "test.local";
string sDefaultOU = "OU=test,DC=test,DC=local";
string sServiceUser = "userwithrights";
string sServicePassword = "somepassword";
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sDomain, sDefaultOU,ContextOptions.SimpleBind, sServiceUser, sServicePassword);
UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, sUserName);
oUserPrincipal.GivenName = "new givenname";
oUserPrincipal.Save();
```

You can find a some helper methods [here](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/).

Code sample for .Net 2.0 which retrieves a user with username "john" and updates the street address of the user. You might have to add credentials to the first line if the app running user don't have rights to edit content.

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server/DC=test,DC=local");
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher( root, "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=john))" );
SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
user.Properties["streetAddress"][0] = "My Street 12";
user.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Hi Mikael, many thanks for replies. I'm still working with a project which is still on .NET 2.0. I really hope I can found a way with System.DirectoryServices. I appreciate your reply. If you have something to share with System.DirectoryService then feel free to share. As a courtesy, I'm accepting it as an answer :)

Comment: Added a sample for your viewing pleasure :)

Comment: The poster was referring to contacts. To my knowledge System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement cannot work with contacts

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement can get and update contacts (I have verified it). However it can not _create_ contacts, only users. It also can not select more than one user/contact based on object guids in one LDAP request.

Comment: @ITHitWebDAV I am really curious about getting contacts that are members of a distribution group with AccountManagement.  If this is what you have verified, could you give a hint or reference as to how it's done.  I have not found any reference to this capability