# Active Directory: unable to add multiple email addresses in multi valued property ("targetaddress")

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to add two different external email addresses for the contacts in the Active Directory. I'm facing the following `COMException`: `A constraint violation occurred.`

```
Here is the DirectoryEntry path= "LDAP://CN=s0010109,OU=RSVContacts,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

Here is the code :

```
DirectoryEntry entryAD = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=s0010109,OU=RSVContacts,DC=domain,DC=com");    

DirectorySearcher myADSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entryAD);
                SearchResultCollection resultAD = myADSearcher.FindAll();              

entryAD.Properties["targetaddress"].Value = new string[] { "SMTP:" + "firstemail@abc.com", ""SMTP:" + secondemail@mail.com"};  //;
entryAD.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what I said in my answer on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058261/how-to-get-update-contacts-within-active-directory), `targetAddress` is not a multi-value attribute.  You cannot do that.  You can only have one single value stored in this attribute.

Comment: Any idea on how I can add multiple external email addresses to a Contact in Active Directory

Comment: @Free Styler, I am not an Exchange expert but on AD, you can only specify one single string to `targetAddress`. This is controlled by AD schema. I googled and found people are using `distribution group` to forward emails to multiple addresses. Hope this help. http://forums.msexchange.org/m_1800424605/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm#1800524542