# Modify attributes in AD via PowerShell (no Quest)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Say I have users and their physicalDeliveryOfficeName attribute, called Office in AD is set to New York, and others say Chicago.

I want to setup a script that will loop through all users.

```
If physicalDeliveryOfficeName = Chicago  
Set address properties   
Street: 8888 Chicago Lane  
City: Chicago  
State: IL  
Zip: 60066  
Country: United States

else if physicalDeliveryOfficeName = New York  
Set address properties  
Street: 9999 New York Lane
City: New York
State: NY
Zip: 11111
Country: United States
```

I can't seem to find out where to start.. any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have PowerShell v2.0, you can use [the built-in Active Directory module](http://www.mikepfeiffer.net/2010/01/how-to-install-the-active-directory-module-for-windows-powershell/), in particular, the [Get-ADUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx) command followed by [Set-ADUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx), something like:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Office -eq "Chicago"} | Set-ADUser -StreetAddress "8888 Chicago Lane City" -City "Chicago" -State "IL" -PostalCode "60066" -Country "US"
```

The full list of available attributes and some examples are available by following the links above or via the `Get-Help` cmdlet.

If you're not on PowerShell v2.0 and can't upgrade for some reason, you can use the [.NET System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace and associated classes, where you should be able to follow reasonably closely the MSDN examples, [e.g. this for updating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180860%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [this example for searching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180885%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). Additionally, Stackoverflow has numerous examples, though [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058261/how-to-get-update-contacts-within-active-directory) looks particularly promising on a quick review.

Also, I missed the [Microsoft example of searching using PowerShell and System.DirectoryServices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730967.aspx).

Comment: this solution is only for standard AD schema. How can I modify the custom attributes without Quest? Thanks

Comment: @AlexYeung: That should probably be asked as a separate question. AFAIK, you're stuck using the .NET classes if you don't want to use Quest. Links are given in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked the above to add/change Address info of employees moving from one location to another.  In the sample below of what I did, of course I changed the address of John Doe.  But this is a one line powershell command line that worked great for those who have not learned scripts yet:

```
get-aduser -filter {SamAccountName -eq "jdoe"} | Set-ADUser -Office "New York" -StreetAddress "123 N Main St" -city "New York" -State "NY" -PostalCode "10044" -Country "US"
```