# Using Powershell, how do I do bulk updates on a certain property for only certain users?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We want to find the users in our domain that have their Office property (i.e. "physicalDeliveryOfficeName") starting with "Student" (e.g. "Student123456", "Student111111", etc.) and clear that Office value out (i.e. set it to ""). Users with a different value for Office, should be left as is. I've tried the following:

```
New-PSDrive -Name AD1 -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Root "OU=BASE,DC=DOMAIN,DC=org"
Set-ItemProperty -Filter {physicalDeliveryOfficeName -Like "Student*"} -Path "ad:\OU=BASE,DC=DOMAIN,DC=org" -Name physicalDeliveryOfficeName -Value "" -WhatIf
```

My output is:

```
What if: Performing operation "Set" on Target "OU=BASE,DC=DOMAIN,DC=org".
```

And that's it. I would expect a "What if" line for each user it found with the matching Office property.

Note that I'm only using a PSDrive, because that's what was mentioned in [this Scripting Guy article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/21/use-the-powershell-ad-provider-to-modify-user-attributes.aspx).

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer: I tried alroc's solution below and saw the WhatIf lines I was looking for. But when I removed the "-Whatif" I got an InvalidOperation error for each user. I ended up using the following code:

```
ForEach ($User in (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Office)){
  If ($User.Office -match "Student*"){
    Set-ADUser $User -Office " "
  }
}
```

Note the space in the new Office property - I got similar errors when using an empty string. Using a space instead of an empty string might have worked with alroc's, but I didn't try it.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quite a bit, to be honest. For starters, you aren't really "finding" the users to change the properties on.

You do not need to create a new PSDrive, for two reasons:

1) If you've got the AD module loaded, there already is one.
2) It's not needed in the first place.

Starting with [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6603715/1324345), a few tweaks and you should be set.

```
get-aduser -filter "*" -property office |
    where-object {$_.office -like 'Student*'} | set-aduser -whatif -office "";
```

Comment: +1. You may even skip the whole `Where-Object` and do it right in `-Filter`:  `Get-ADUser -Filter { office -like "Student*" }`... Also you don't need `-Property office` in `Get-ADUser` to do a `Set-ADUser -office`.

Comment: You do need the `-property office` if you use the `where-object` in my original code. I can't get the filter you're suggesting to work; my gut tells me it *should* work but it's not happening.

Comment: Interesting that `-Filter` is not working. I'll test again tomorrow on versions 2, 3 and 4.