# Retrieving Street Address property of Active Directory DirectoryEntry

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a collection of Active Directory user DirectoryEntries and I need to get the street address associated with each. I'm using something along the lines of:

```
    bool TryGetPropertyValue(DirectoryEntry de, string propertyName, out string propertyValue)
    {
        if (de.Properties.Contains(propertyName) && de.Properties[propertyName].Count > 0)
        {
            propertyValue = de.Properties[propertyName][0].ToString();
            return true;
        }
        propertyValue = string.Empty;
        return false;
    }
```

But I can't find a value of `propertyName` that will get the address of the user. Does one exist, or is there another way to get this information?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058261/how-to-get-update-contacts-within-active-directory

Comment: "Address", "Address-Home", "Registered-Address" and "Street-Address" are address-related items on the User-class in windows AD you could try one of those. The complete list can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683980(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful of the way you get `DirectoryEntry de`. On pure LDAP point of view, it's better to specify during a directory search the attributes that you really want to retreive. I know that most of developpers suppose that all attributes should be retreive, but on the LDAP point of view it's not so evident :

```
/* Connection to Active Directory
 */
string sFromWhere = "LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/dc=dom,dc=fr";
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, "dom\\jpb", "root.123");

DirectorySearcher dsLookFor = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
dsLookFor.Filter = "(CN=user1 Users)";
dsLookFor.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
// Add one line for each property you need.
dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("...");


SearchResultCollection srcUsers = dsLookFor.FindAll();
```

On the attributes names point of view you'd better refer to [Active Directory Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and specialy [All atributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

In order to link an attribute with an entry field in the user and computer Active-Directory MMC you can use LDP.EXE (which is native in W2K8, and come from the ressource kit in W2K3). Another interesting tool is [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/). It works on all plateforms (Linux (MAC), Microsoft) and allow you to browse the Directory and the Schema.