# active directory findone() method

Tags: c#, active-directory

im trying to inquire Ad by using this line`s

```
            DirectoryEntry de = null;
            SearchResult results = null;
            de = new DirectoryEntry();

            //geting the result FROM ad
            de.Path = dr.manager;
            de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(de);
            search.Filter = string.Format("(objectClass={0})",'*');
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("IsraelID");
            results = search.FindOne();
            de = results.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

but im getting an exception in the findone()

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string LDAP = "LDAP://DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM";
using (DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
    using (DirectorySearcher dirSearch = new DirectorySearcher(
        dirEntry,
        string.Concat("(objectClass=*)"),
        new string[] { "IsraelID" }))
    {
        SearchResult result = dirSearch.FindOne();
        if (result != null)
            return result.Properties["IsraelID"][0].ToString();
        else
            return null;
    }
```

**Note:** The string.Concat() around the "(objectClass=*)" statement is there because It's common to add additional statements or variables there.

Make sure you have a proper LDAP string, and I would suggest using statements to make sure you dispose of everything afterwards.

Comment: So, what exactly is the difference with the originally posted code? Any idea what the actual error was? Only real thing I see is using a constructor with properties, instead of setting them manually afterwards.

Answer (score 11):

Unspecified error means, that your LDAP path is missing the LDAP protocol identifier.
Ensure that your path contains the LDAP protocol identifier in upper case.

Example:

```
DirectoryEntry de = null; 
SearchResult results = null; 
de = new DirectoryEntry(); 

// Assuming your domain dns name is treyresearch.net 
de.Path = "LDAP://servername/CN=users,DC=treyresearch,DC=net"; 
de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure; 
de.Username = "treyresearch\\Administrator";
de.Password = "P@$$W0rd";
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(de); 
search.Filter = string.Format("(objectClass={0})",'*'); 
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("IsraelID"); 
results = search.FindOne(); 
de = results.GetDirectoryEntry();
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer, considering it may not get marked as one.

Answer (score 1):

acutely my mistake was much more basic than the exception mentioned ..
i wrote  this wrong active directory statement

```
de.path=dr.dr.manager
```

when i added "LDAP://" to the statement it solve it

```
de.Path = "LDAP://"+dr.manager;
```

thanks allot for the support

Comment: If that's the case, maybe you should at least select Hans answer as the correct answer. He specifically stated that (I did as well, but he did a few minutes before me).

Answer (score 0):

try yhis way :

```
/* Connection to Active Directory
 */
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/dc=dom,dc=fr", "jpb", "Pwd");
//DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/dc=dom,dc=fr");

/* Directory Search
 */
DirectorySearcher dsLookForOUs = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
dsLookForOUs.Filter = "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)";
dsLookForOUs.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dsLookForOUs.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
dsLookForOUs.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ou");

SearchResultCollection srcOUs = dsLookForOUs.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult srOU in srcOUs)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}", srOU.Path);

}
```

In this case I authenticate as a user and a password. If you run the program from a computer inside the domain, you don't need to authenticate. You've got a good sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058261/how-to-get-update-contacts-within-active-directory/5061571#5061571).