# Find all users in Ldap using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Below is my code. I want to retrieve all the users whose first name or last name is same in a grid. But here am getting the name itself in the grid sorted.

I'm giving user a choice to enter user name. Once he enter the name I should be able to search in Active Directory and return all user starting with that text entered by the user.

I should be able to display all possibilities, for example if user enters `adam` I should give him choice to select whether he want to see `adam josef` or `adam john` e.t.c.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Here is the code

```
       DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("ADConnection");

        DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);

        //set the search filter    
        deSearch.SearchRoot = de;
        String UserName = txt_To.Text;
        deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(GivenName=*" + UserName + "*))";
        string[] arrPropertiesToLoad = { "sn" };
        deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(arrPropertiesToLoad);

      SearchResultCollection sResultColl = deSearch.FindAll();//Getting undefined error



        Gridview1.DataSource = sResultColl ;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Here is the stack trace

> [COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error]
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +439513
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +36
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +31
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne) +78
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll() +9
>   Certificate.WebForm4.btngo0_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\273714\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Certificate\Certificate\WebForm4.aspx.cs:202
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +112
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +5563

Comment: If the username i give is sam, in the grid am getting it as S A M in vertical line. If i uncomment the lines am getting undefined exception.

Comment: what do you mean undefined exception? Could you show this exception and callstack?

Comment: The stack trace is in the question. I changed the code by uncommenting the lines. Where am i gng wrong? :(

Comment: Call stack- > Certificate.DLL!Certificate.WebForm4.btngo0_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 202 + 0xa bytes C#

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892655/active-directory-findone-method

Comment: What **exactly** is your `ADConnection` ? Can you show us the full LDAP path you're using there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce" and a last name (Surname) of "Miller"
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.GivenName = "*" + UserName + "*";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

**Update:** if you want to find a bunch of users and bind those to a gridview, use this code:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce" and a last name (Surname) of "Miller"
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.GivenName = "*" + UserName + "*";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

var results = srch.FindAll();

Gridview1.DataSource = results; 
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Don't iterate twice over all the data returned! (as in your comment
) .....

**Update #2:** with the S.DS.AM classes, you **always** get the complete class - there's nothing you can do about this. If you want to select *only* specific LDAP attributes, you need to use your original approach.

From that approach, you need to make sure to create the root of the `DirectorySearcher` on a **container** - e.g. the `OU=Users` container - **NOT** on an individual AD object like a specific user.

So try using this code:

```
// define a *CONTAINER* as the root of your searcher!
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Users,OU=NJY,OU=NewJersey,OU=USA,OU=NorthAmerica,OU=America,OU=gunt,DC=xxx,DC=com");

DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);

// set the search filter    
string UserName = txt_To.Text;

deSearch.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=user)(givenName=*{0}*))", UserName);
deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");

SearchResultCollection sResultColl = deSearch.FindAll();

Gridview1.DataSource = sResultColl;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Does that work?

Comment: I think i got what i wanted ..but how can i bind the result to grid.i used Gridview1.DataSource = found;
                Gridview1.DataBind(); but got error

Comment: its taking very long time.is there a way to reduce the time, like just displaying the firstname with last name or anything like that.

Comment: foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
            {
                string result = srch.FindAll().ToString();
                Gridview1.DataSource = result;
                Gridview1.DataBind();// do // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
            } This is how i have used

Comment: @user1665707: **no wonder** it's slow! You're iterating over all users found, and then you're doing a `.FindAll()` again - for each user...... see my update

Comment: Its working.:) But am getting all the details of the user. I nedd to restrict it just to given name and sur name.Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Anu idea how to get just cn?

Comment: I again get unspecified error at this line SearchResultCollection sResultColl = deSearch.FindAll();

Comment: @user1665707: does the user running this code have permission to query AD? Can you try to specify another user maybe (in the constructor of the `DirectoryEntry`) - does that work?

Comment: No I get the same error. am using   DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("ldap://burt.xxx.com:389/ou=users", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

            DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);

Comment: @user1665707: are you using **lower-case** on the `ldap://` - that won't work - you **MUST** use **UPPERCASE**! Try `LDAP:// .....` - does that work?

Comment: Strange that the approach with `PrincipalContext` works... can you try that code again? When the `PrincipalContext` object is created - can you look at its properties? Where does it connect to? What LDAP server and/or container? Maybe you're trying to bind to a container that's not valid/not accessible to you .....

Comment: When the principalContext object is created the connection server is correct and the container is null.

Comment: Hey i was using a wrong LDAP string. The code is working now but still i get distinguished names along with the name i want.But i just want the display name in the grid.

Comment: @user1665707: the `distinguishedName` is **always** returned - you cannot turn that off.

Comment: Oh fine then will speak to the concerned person regarding this. Thank You for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(givenName=*" + UserName + "*))";
```

Works fine