# Get all users that have ever logged into a pc with c#

Tags: c#, user-profile

I'm trying to retrieve all the users that have ever logged into a pc and populate them in a combobox, but after searching, I'm not finding any good answers.

I was going to look at the:

```
DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE")).Parent.GetDirectories();
```

But I feel that is way to unreliable.

Next I was going to look at the registry, but after reading, that list will not update if a user account name has ever been changed.  I know there has to be a record of all the user profiles on a machine, because I have used Microsoft systernals tools to manage them.  but I just cannot figure out how to do it programatically with c#.

Comment: Just to clairify, this is where the list is stored: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7248788/profiles.PNG    the WMI query seems to return every user in my domain, i only want local profiles stored on pc, but domain profiles.  (i cropped out the profiles from the pic, there are 4 profiles on my pc now).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, well, i figured this out, actually with WMI after all, here is my code.

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Management;
private void GetLocalUserAccounts()
{
     SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserProfile");
     ManagementObjectsSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
     foreach (ManagementObject sid in searcher.Get())
     {
          MessageBox.Show(new SecurityIdentifier(sid["SID"].ToString()).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
     }
}
```

This also returns the system accounts IE: NT_Authority NT_System, but those can be filtered easily.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I had an error where ManagementObjectsSearcher could not be found (even with the using System.Management; and including it to my references) I fixed this by changing:   ManagementObjectsSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query); TO
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query); Hope that helps if anyone else has the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take a look at [WMI](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb742445.aspx). It allows you to run sql-like queries on a machine to get loads of system informations.

Some inspiration in VBScript : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/2b99b836-ed8f-4146-89e4-947b79bf4862/

Answer (score 1):

If the user is created on the local machine, it should have a user folder, as Joshua said.

Also, you could try running CMD's "net user" command and capturing the return value using something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16081/CommandLineHelper-class-to-launch-console-applicat).

Edit: per the comments below, check this out and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8455654/1046689

Comment: i appologize, i should have been more specific in my question.   i actually am more concerned with domain user profiles.

Comment: i have found a WMI query similar to that, but i returns everyuser in my domain, i only want to know domain users that have logged on the pc running the application.

Comment: I think this will mostly depend on your domain settings. In my company, for example, if a user logs in using a domain account, their Users\[user name] directory is created and copied from the domain server. So if I were making such a list in my company, I'd do something like get the list of domain users via WMI then cross reference that list with the list of local users and remove any that aren't in both.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the %windir%\Users directory ommitting default folder names (public/admin etc) and parse out the usernames from the filenames

Comment: I think that's what the OP had already considered. `GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE").Parent()` is `%windir%\Users`